# Verificar si un arreglo tiene valores repetidos

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo un cuadrado mágico (sudoku) y necesito un código para que los números no se repitan pero no se que usar, ¿pueden ayudarme?

Este es el principal, como el nombre de la clase dice:

```
public class Principal {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Operaciones op=new Operaciones();
        int n=0,c=0,f=0;
        System.out.println("3x3"+"\t"+"4x4"+"\t"+"5x5");
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad por la sea el cuadrado: ");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        int arr[][]=new int[n][n];
        int cont[]=new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                int h=0;
                System.out.print("Ingrese el numero en la posicion "+"("+(i+1)+","+(k+1)+")"+": ");
                arr[i][k]=sc.nextInt();
                cont[h]=arr[i][k];
                if(op.valida(cont,n,h,k)){

                }
                else{
                    k--;
                }
                h++;

            }
        }
```

y esta es la clase donde hago las operaciones:

```
package cuadrado.magico;


public class Operaciones {

    public static boolean valida(int cont[],int n,int h, int k){
        if(n==3){
            if(cont[h]>=1&&cont[h]<=9){               
                return true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("VALOR NO CORRECTO");
                k--;
                return false;
            }

        }
        if(n==4){
            if(cont[h]>=1&&cont[h]<=16){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("VALOR NO CORRECTO");
                k--;
                return false;
            }

        }
        if(n==5){
            if(cont[h]>=1&&cont[h]<=25){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("VALOR NO CORRECTO");
                k--;
                return false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("VALOR NO CORRECTO");
        k--;
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean columnas(int h[]){

        return false;
    }
```

Obviamente no están completas, solo necesito su ayuda con el código para que no se repitan. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: la pregunta es como saber en que cuadrante buscar los valores, la fila y la columna lo tienes? sencillo sabemos que cada cuadrante es de 3x3, con esa referencia sabiendo la columna y la fila tenemos que el modulo de la fila / 3 es donde empieza puedes hacer algo  como `fila_inicio_cuadrante = Math.ceil(fila_entrada % 3); columna_inicio = Math.ceil(columna_entrada% 3); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Mario aqui esta mi respuesta

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=0;
        System.out.println("3x3"+"\t"+"4x4"+"\t"+"5x5");
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad por la sea el cuadrado: ");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        int arr[][]=new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {

                System.out.print("Ingrese el numero en la posicion "+"("+(i+1)+","+(k+1)+")"+": ");
                int in=sc.nextInt();

                if(valida(arr,in)){

                    arr[i][k]=in;

                }else {

                    System.out.println("Numero repetido, ingrese otra vez posicion "+"("+(i+1)+","+(k+1)+")"+": ");
                    k--;
                }

            }
        }


}
```

este metodo puede estar en l amisma clase

```
 public static boolean valida(int arr[][],int in){
     boolean valida=true;
        int largo=arr.length;
     for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < largo; j++) {
            if(arr[i][j]==in) {
                valida=false;
            }
        }

    }

        return valida;
    }
```

Disculpa si te cambie un poco tu codigo, creo que talvez tenias variables de mas.

Comment: gracias si fue de utilidad